# Angular Material virtual repeat (on demand) repeates first loaded bunch of items twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

I'm working on Angular (version 1.4.9) Material [virtual repeat deferred loading](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) and slightly modified the example code.

My code loads 15 items per page from a REST resource and displayes them in the list.
But my list shows the first 15, **then repeats the first 15 (the mistake!)** and then loads the next bunch of items (16 to 30 and so on). I'can't find the problem, any ideas why that happens?

**The code from html file:**

```
<div class="virtualRepeat">
<md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
  <md-list>
    <md-list-item md-virtual-repeat="user in listCtrl.userData" md-on-demand class="md-2-line" flex>
      <div class="md-list-item-text">
        Name: {{user.name}}
        ID: {{user.id}}
      </div>
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>
</md-virtual-repeat-container>
</div>
```

**The code from the controller:**

```
...
var vm = this;

var ListItems = function() {
  this.count = 0;
  this.pageSize = 15;
  this.loadedPages = {};
  this.listData = [];
  this.getUserCount_();
}

ListItems.prototype.getItemAtIndex = function(index) {
  var currentPage = Math.floor(index / this.pageSize);
  var page = this.loadedPages[currentPage];
  if (page) {
    return this.listData[index];
  } else if (page !== null) {
    this.getPage_(currentPage);
  }
}

ListItems.prototype.getLength = function() {
  return this.count;
}

ListItems.prototype.getPage_ = function(currentPage) {
  this.loadedPages[currentPage] = null; 
  this.loadedPages[currentPage] = [];

  var pageOffset = currentPage * this.pageSize;

  for (var i = pageOffset; i < pageOffset + this.pageSize; i++) {
    this.loadedPages[currentPage].push(i);
  }

  RestFactory.fetchCurrentPage(currentPage).then(angular.bind(this, function(users) {
    for(var i = 0; i < users.items.length; i++) {
      this.listData.push({
        name: users.items[i].name,
        id: users.items[i].id
      });
    }
  }));

}

ListItems.prototype.getUserCount_ = function() {
  RestFactory.fetchUserCount().then(angular.bind(this, function(count) {
    this.userCount = count;
  }));
}

vm.userData = new ListItems();
...
```

Comment: its chard to spot the problem in code. can you create a demo of your code? for example by modifying the initial one http://codepen.io/shershen08/pen/YwoKYP?#

Comment: I can't recreate this weird behaviour on a codepen

Comment: This possibly means that reason for the duplication of the first 15 rows in some other part of you code. You can try to flush that part/module completely and start from code exactly copied from virtual repeat documentation

Comment: Thanks for trying @shershen it's solved. giving another parameter to fetchCurrentPage()